# Angular-ui fixed custom navbar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

In my Ionic Angular app, using angular-ui-router,

I was wondering how to make one custom back button for all the app's views, as I want every back button to be the same and to link to the same page.

My index page looks like this:

```
 <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable bar-positive">
  <ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>


<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
```

But the problem is changing

```
  <ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-back-button>
```

won't do the trick, as these get automaticly updated when a new page is entered.
Would there be a way to prevent this changing?

Comment: Can you provide a full working example?

Comment: I haven't found one yet, but I guess it should be possible as I'm basically replacing an advanced feature (dynamic navbar) by an easier one (static navbar)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what custom directives you are using, but to create a link to specific view in any page of your app using pure AngularUI Router - you can use [ui-sref](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref) attribute, the syntax then is as follows:

```
<a ui-sref="{YOUR_STATE_NAME}" ui-sref-opts="{OPTIONAL_PARAMS}">link</a>
<!--it can be also a <button>-->
```

Comment: that line would do the trick, but the very question is how I can put this in the navbar. when i put this in the `ion-nav-bar` , it isn't displayed smh